# XsltListViewWebPart: select default view

Tags: list-view, deployment, xslt-list-view-web-part, provisioning, viewfields

I'm trying to configure an `XsltLisViewWebPart` for deployment to a SharePoint site. I'm provisioning the views beforehand using:

```
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list.Title);
clientContext.Load(oList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

ViewCreationInformation viewCreationInformation = new ViewCreationInformation();
viewCreationInformation.Title = "DefaultNotificationsViewJSLink";
viewCreationInformation.ViewTypeKind = ViewType.None;
viewCreationInformation.RowLimit = 30;

viewCreationInformation.ViewFields = new string[] { "Title", "Created" };
viewCreationInformation.SetAsDefaultView = true;

oList.Views.Add(viewCreationInformation);

clientContext.Load(oList.Views);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I'm using following template for the .aspx pages:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart 
runat="server" 
ViewFlag="" 
ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" 
InplaceSearchEnabled="False" 
ServerRender="False" 
ClientRender="True" 
InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" 
WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
IsClientRender="False" 
GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" 
NoDefaultStyle="" 

EnableOriginalValue="False" 
ViewContentTypeId="" 
ListUrl="./Lists/Notifications" 
ListDisplayName="" 


PageSize="-1" 
UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" 
DataSourceID="" 
ShowWithSampleData="False" 
AsyncRefresh="False" 
ManualRefresh="False" 
AutoRefresh="False" 
AutoRefreshInterval="60" 
Title="Notifications" 
FrameType="Default" 
SuppressWebPartChrome="False" 
Description="Notifications" 
IsIncluded="True" 
ZoneID="Header" 
PartOrder="0" 
FrameState="Normal" 
AllowRemove="True" 
AllowZoneChange="True" 
AllowMinimize="True" 
AllowConnect="True" 
AllowEdit="True" 
AllowHide="True" 
IsVisible="True" 
CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png?rev=36" 
TitleUrl="./Lists/Notifications" 
DetailLink="./Lists/Notifications" 
HelpLink="" 
HelpMode="Modeless" 
Dir="Default" 
PartImageSmall="" 
MissingAssembly="Kan dit webonderdeel niet importeren." 
ImportErrorMessage="Kan dit webonderdeel niet importeren." 
PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png?rev=36" 
IsIncludedFilter="" 
ExportControlledProperties="False" 
ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 


__MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" 

__AllowXSLTEditing="true" 
__designer:CustomXsl="Fldtypes_mswhTitle.xsl;fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" 
WebPart="true" 
Height="" 
Width=""><ParameterBindings>
 <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
 <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
 <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
 <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>

 <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
 <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
 <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
 <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
<ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
<ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
</ParameterBindings>

<JsLink>~sitecollection/Style Library/JSLink/JsLinkTiles.js</JsLink>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<XmlDefinition>

<View Name="DefaultNotificationsViewJSLink" 
MobileView="TRUE" 
Type="HTML" 
Hidden="TRUE" 
DisplayName="" 
Url="./SitePages/EmptyPage_SP01.aspx" 
Level="1" 
BaseViewID="1" 
ContentTypeID="0x" 
ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=37" >
<Query>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name="ID"/>
</OrderBy>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Title"/>
<FieldRef Name="Created"/>
</ViewFields>
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
<JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
<XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
<Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
</View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

The views are provisioned correctly. (I can select them when I edit the list view web part.) The problem is that SharePoint ignores the  - nodes in the ASPX page and excludes them. Therefore, the list will render but there are no columns shown.

Which template should I use for the `XsltListViewWebPart` for it to show its default view? Or any other provisioned view, for that matter?

Thanks in advance!